# Console.Read() method doesn't wait

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    countValues();
}

static void countValues()
{
    float value1;
    float value2;
    float result;
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number");
    value1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.Read());
    Console.WriteLine("Give another number");
    value2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.Read());

    result = value1 + value2;

    Console.WriteLine("You gave numbers " + value1 + " and " + value2);
    Console.WriteLine("Together these values are " + result);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this code? It's a long time that I last used C# and I've forgotten everything about it. When I run this piece of code it asks for a number. When I enter some number it prints everything without never asking for number two.

Comment: Perhaps read the [documentation (link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of `Console.Read()`. I've never used C# at all, yet it's clear to me (after reading the very first line of the documentation) what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.Read()` only reads one character. So your code will only read two characters, one digit for each number.

Use `Console.ReadLine()` if you want the user to have to press the `Enter` key to terminate input of a single number.

Answer (score 1):

issue with Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine();

**Use Console.ReadLine();**

```
static void countValues()
{

    float value1;
    float value2;
    float result;
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number");
    value1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Give another number");
    value2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

    result = value1 + value2;

    Console.WriteLine("You gave numbers " + value1 + " and " + value2);
    Console.WriteLine("Together these values are " + result);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Why would OP want to use `Console.ReadLine()` vs `Console.Read()`?  Just dumping a code snippet is not an answer.

Comment: he already worked on C#, hope fully this will trigger whats the wrong.. he can catch whats the difference between `Read() vs ReadLine()`

Comment: And if someone else comes along later who is just starting in C#?  The idea behind SO is to create answers that are useful for anyone.